# How to create single observable value?

Tags: tornadofx

I've got a top-level Controller object that is holding a reference to three objects (`MyObject`). I'd like to position these precisely on the page at any time, but I would like each object to also be editable, and I'm not really sure how to do that.

So far, I've got a class that extends `ItemFragment` and displays my individual items, like this:

```
class MyObjectFragment(o: MyObject) : ItemFragment<MyObject>() {

  override val root = hbox {
    ...
  }
}
```

Meanwhile, I have a top-level View with a reference to my controller, like this:

```
class TopLevelView : View() {

  val controller = TopLevelController()

  override val root = hbox {
    add(MyObjectFragment(controller.myObject1))
    ...
    add(MyObjectFragment(controller.myObject2))
    ...
    add(MyObjectFragment(controller.myObject3))
  }
}
```

And right now, all I have for the top level controller is this:

```
class TopLevelController() : Controller() {
  val myObject1 = MyObject()
  val myObject2 = MyObject()
  val myObject3 = MyObject()
}
```

I'm trying to figure out what I need to do to wrap these objects as observable values. My first attempt was to add something like this to the init method of `MyObjectFragment`:

```
class MyObjectFragment(o: MyObject) : ItemFragment<MyObject>() {

  init {
    itemProperty.bind(o)
  }

  ...
}
```

However, that method only takes an `ObservableValue<MyObject>`. What is the best way to get that to tie all of this together?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an observable list of your objects like so:

```
class TopLevelController() : Controller() {
  val myObjects = FXCollections.observableArrayList<MyObject>(MyObject(), MyObject(), MyObject())
}
```

Then in your `TopLevelView`, you can bind this list to a layout node's children property, and inflate the proper Fragment for each object:

```
class TopLevelView : View() {

  val controller = TopLevelController()

  override val root = hbox {
    bindChildren(controller.myObjects) {
      MyObjectFragment(it).root
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit your requirements seem a little vague to me without more information. It'd be helpful to know more of what you want from the item fragments. Are they going to be in a list view or table? Or something more dynamic? And how exactly would they be editing? Would there be a save button or would you expect any input to commit those changes immediately?

```
import tornadofx.*

class MyObject() {
    //val someProperty = SimpleObjectProperty<Something>()
    //var some by someProperty
}

class MyObjectModel(myObject: MyObject? = null) : ItemViewModel<MyObject>(myObject) {
    //val someBinding = bind(MyObject::someProperty)
}

class MyObjectFragment : ItemFragment<MyObject>() {
    val model: MyObjectModel by inject()

    override val root = hbox {
        label("This is an MyObject Fragment")
        //you would bind some control to the model binding in here. For example:
        //textfield(model.someBinding)
    }

    init {
        itemProperty.value = model.item
        model.bindTo(this)
    }
}

class TopLevelController : Controller() {
    val myObject1 = MyObject()
    val myObject2 = MyObject()
    val myObject3 = MyObject()
}

class TopLevelView  : View() {
    val controller: TopLevelController by inject()

    override val root = vbox {
        add(setUpObjectFragment(controller.myObject1))
        add(setUpObjectFragment(controller.myObject2))
        add(setUpObjectFragment(controller.myObject3))
    }

    fun setUpObjectFragment(obj: MyObject) = find<MyObjectFragment>(Scope(MyObjectModel(obj)))
}
```

It also seems you're new and are missing a lot of key concepts to utilize from TornadoFX. Using `find` for instance, is really important for `Fragments` and `Views` so they have the proper life cycle.

Then there's `Scope`s which help with being able to call certain Components with injection.

And finally, there are `Model` classes, most importantly `ItemViewModel` which gives you the most functionality with editing, like being able to rollback and commit changes as well as to mark properties as `required` and add `validate` filters.

If this isn't a satisfactory solution, please give us more information on what you want, as I might be able to provide a more elegant and concise solution. If these concepts are confusing, please look at [Edvin's guide](https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx-guide).